# c# how to process two argus which uncertain type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, abp

**What I want: A function to record the changes after modification**

In my application, people can modify data, and I want to record what data is modified

**What I tried: Generic**

I use abp, and I need to compare the entity (the old data) and the InputDto (new data), so I wrote a function to convert an entity or a dto to a dictionary, and then I compare the differences between the two dictionaries to get the changes.

This is my convert funciton:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ConverModelToDict<T>(T model)
{
    Type t = model.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] propertyList = t.GetProperties();

    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyList)
    {
        string name = item.Name;

        if (item.GetValue(model) != null)
        {
            object value = item.GetValue(model);
            result.Add(name, value.ToString());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I wrote another function to get an entity and a dto to compare:

```
public async Task<string> CompareEntityAndDto<T, K>(T oldModel, K newModel, string moduleName)
    {
        var oldDict = ConverModelToDict(oldModel);
        var newDict = ConverModelToDict(newModel);

        string result = "";

        foreach (var key in newDict.Keys)
        {
            if (oldDict.ContainsKey(key) && newDict[key] != oldDict[key])
            {
                var value = "【" + oldDict[key] + "】" + "changeTo" + "【" + newDict[key] + "】";
                result += key + ":" + value + ";";
            }
        }

        string detial = moduleName + result;
        return detial;
    }
```

`oldModel` is the entity which is a Database query result, `newmodel` is a dto from form-data, `moduleName` is just a string, this is how I call the function in my application

```
await _compareAppService.CompareEntityAndDto(query, input, "somestring");
```

and I got the error:

> System.NotImplementedException: IsValid(object value) has not been implemented by this class.  The preferred entry point is GetValidationResult() and classes should override IsValid(object value. ValidationContext context).
>      at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value. ValidationContext validationContext)
>      at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object value. ValidationContext validationContext)
>      at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.DataAnnotationsValidator.GetDataAnnotationAttributeErrors(Object validatingObject) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Runtime\Validation\Interception\DataAnnotationsValidator.cs:line 38
>      at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.MethodInvocationValidator.SetValidationErrors(Object validatingObject) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Runtime\Validation\Interception\MethodInvocationValidator.cs:line 208
>      at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.MethodInvocationValidator.ValidateObjectRecursively(Object validatingObject. Int32 currentDepth) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Runtime\Validation\Interception\MethodInvocationValidator.cs:line 168
>      at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.MethodInvocationValidator.ValidateObjectRecursively(Object validatingObject. Int32 currentDepth) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Runtime\Validation\Interception\MethodInvocationValidator.cs:line 188
>      at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.MethodInvocationValidator.Validate() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Runtime\Validation\Interception\MethodInvocationValidator.cs:line 82
>      at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.ValidationInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Runtime\Validation\Interception\ValidationInterceptor.cs:line 30
>      at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
>      at XX.XXXXManage.XXXXManages.XXXXAppService.StudentEditRecord(StuRecordDto input) in D:\coding\XXXXXX\src\XX.Application\XXXXManage\XXXXManages\XXXXAppService.cs:line 178
>      at lambda_method(Closure . Object )
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper. ObjectMethodExecutor executor. Object controller. Object[] arguments)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next. Scope& scope. Object& state. Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()

How can I fix this error, or is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: Which line is throwing that exception? I have a feeling you haven't shared that part.

Comment: when the Breakpoint run to  `await _compareAppService.CompareEntityAndDto(query, input, "somestring"); `

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception? The exception is not thrown by anything you're showing. It's also a good example of why nothing should ever throw `NotImplementedException`. That exception means, "instead of just not having this property or method, I have this property or method, and when you call it, I'll throw an exception saying that I don't really have this property or method."

Comment: @217LeeSin The exception states *"IsValid(object value) has not been implemented by this class"*. Presumably that happens somewhere during the call to `CompareEntityAndDto`. Find that method and implement it.

Comment: @Scott Hannen I have update the error message,but I am not sure is that you want

Comment: @217LeeSin Does CompareEntityAndDto has any custom validation related annotations or is it implementing any interface that has IsValid method? Could you post CompareEntityAndDto class ?

Comment: @sam nope, the breakpoint Can't even jump into CompareEntityAndDto method, when it run to `await _compareAppService.CompareEntityAndDto(query, input, "somestring")`, I got the error

Comment: by the way , ConverModelToDict method need one argument, but the type of the argument is uncertain , so I write the method with `ConverModelToDict<T>(T model)`, and CompareEntityAndDto need two uncertain type arguments, so I write it `CompareEntityAndDto<T, K>(T oldModel, K newModel, string moduleName)`, I am not sure It is wrote in correct way

Comment: @217LeeSin  I am sorry I meant to check the user input data DTO whether it contains any validations, not CompareEntityAndDto. StackTrace shows the method StudentEditRecord at line number 178. Could you verify that?

Comment: The stacktrace is enough to know that the exception absolutely 100% does not involve the code you're looking at. The methods you're calling in the code are not mentioned in the stacktrace. They're not getting called. They're being thrown by an interceptor, something that gets called before your code gets called. So at the very least you don't have to look in this code.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840567/isvalidobject-value-has-not-been-implemented-by-this-class